# Place a window behind any other existing third party window

Tags: windows, delphi, forms, positioning, z-order

In order to take a screenshot of a specific window, I need to place a white colored TForm behind that window. What Windows API could I use to change the z-order of my window and place it correctly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [`SetWindowPos()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. And for the record, it's not that easy to use as you have to make sure that 1- the form's owner is the desktop so it can freely change z-order and 2- You call that function using the SWP_NOACTIVATE flag. Thank you for the fast response.

Answer (score 1):

On Delphi you can use`SendToBack` method, `.Top` and `.Left` properties.

```
form1.Top := ...;
form1.Left := ...;
form1.SendToBack;
```

> procedure SendToBack;
>
> Description
>
> Use SendToBack to change the order of
>   overlapping controls or forms.
>
> The order in which controls stack on
>   top of each other (also called the Z
>   order) depends on the order the
>   controls are placed on the form. For
>   example, if you put a label and an
>   image on a form so that one is on top
>   of the other, the one that was placed
>   first on the form becomes the one on
>   the bottom. Because both the label and
>   the image are non-windowed controls,
>   they "stack" as you would expect them
>   to. Call the SendToBack method for the
>   top object to move it below the other
>   object.
>
> The stacking order of two windowed
>   controls is the same as the stacking
>   of two non-windowed controls. For
>   example, if you put a memo on a form,
>   then put a check box on top of it, the
>   check box remains on top. Calling
>   SendToBack for the check box makes the
>   memo appear on top.
>
> The stacking order of windowed and
>   non-windowed controls cannot be
>   mingled. For example, if you put a
>   memo, a windowed control, on a form,
>   and then put a label, a non-windowed
>   control, on top of it, the label
>   disappears behind the memo. Windowed
>   controls always stack on top of
>   non-windowed controls. In this
>   example, calling the SendToBack method
>   of the memo does nothing, the label
>   remains behind the memo.
>
> If the control has the input focus
>   when the SendToBack method executes,
>   it loses the input focus.

(Edit: [WinSnap](http://www.ntwind.com/software/winsnap.html) is a very good utility for taking and editing screenshots)

Comment: He wants the white form *immediately* behind the target window, not behind *all* other windows. I suspect he wants the white background so that Windows XP's curved corners and Windows Vista's glass borders aren't sullied by other arbitrary patterns behind them.

Comment: Exactly Rob. The solution was to use the SetWindowsPos() API as suggested by mghie.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the handle of the window you want in front then I would assume that:
Pseudo Code:

```
MyAppWindow.BringToFront
```

followed by

```
TargetWindow.BringToFront
```

Should have the desired effect, yes?